# Where in Kiev airport can I find power outlets?

Tags: airports, power, kyiv, kbp

I have a long layover in Kiev Boryspil and would like to recharge my computer. Where can I find some electrical plugs on the airport grounds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went through all floors of Terminal D and the only available plugs were in the domestic departures area (2nd floor), opposite the check-in desks. The outlets are under the "Telephones" sign, as well as under the nearby seats. Picture of exact location below:

[image: kiev airport plugs]

There were also similar 'charge stations' on the departures floor, but they didn't have any seats nearby.